# How can I bring all the used ASCII characters of a file into a dictionary/array/list and assign each character a value?

Tags: java, python

I basically want to read a file (could be an mp3 file or whatever). Scan the file for all the used ASCII characters of the file and put them into an dictionary, array or list. And then from there assign each character a number value.

For example:

Let's say I load in the file blabla.mp3
(Obviously this type of file is encoded so it won't be just plain english characters.)

This is it's contents:

╤dìúúH»╓╒:φººMQ╤╤╤╤┤i↔↔←GGGΦ⌠i←E::2E┤tti←╙╤ΦΦ⌠·:::::%Fæ╤╤:6Å⌠tSN│èëåD¿╢ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅO^↔:::.ÄÄÄÄÄÄèHΦΦ■ï»ó⌐╙-↔→E┤tttttttt}▲î╤╤dì"Ü:::)ú$tm‼º╤╓q╤╙·:.ñÇ°"V├╡ΦPa↨/úúúúúúΦ╞îHΦ║*ÄèúóΦΦΦΦ»DΦΦ·tΘ○_Nïúkî►"DëÜ)#ú»→·:4Äïúúúúúó¿║:(  ·:ç↑PR"$RGH◄◘úúó¿ΦΦΦΦ┌&HΦΦ┌+⌠WºGG ╤m→GF╘±"¿ΦñïúúúóΦò↨FæTtt╓ìú⌠ΦΦΦ⌠z:::=:::::≥E╤╤╤╤╤╤╤Tm↔↔▬Hªèi⌠ztz:::tt

I want to figure out what characters are being used and assign each one a value from 0 - 255 and each value will be unique to that character.

So ╤ = 0; Φ = 56; ú = 25 etc etc etc

Now I've been searching the python and java docs and I'm not so sure I know what I'm searching for. And I don't know if I should be worrying about ASCII characters or HEX or the raw bytes of the file.

I just need someone to point me in the right direction. Any help?

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from that are associated with each character?

Answer (score 1):

Each byte  *is* a number from 0 to 255. An array containing those numbers is, precisely, an array containing the contents of the file. I'm not at all clear on what you want to do with this array (or dictionary, etc) but making it is going to be easy.

Comment: In Java, that's wrong. Each byte is a number from -128 to 127. The only unsigned integer type in Java is `char`.

Comment: Well... yeah. Except you can just do `theByte & 0xFF` to do the conversion.

Comment: That converts it to an `int` value (which may be fine for OP's purposes). It's no longer a `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Each byte you read in already is a value between 0 and 255 (thus a byte). Is there a reason you can't just use that?

Comment: If it's a `byte` primitive type, it's a value between -128 and 127.

Comment: @TedHopp Sorry I was thinking of c, either way you can easily bump it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to accomplish. You can create a `char` array of length 256. Each entry stores the character you want to associate with that index. If you want to go the other way, I recommend a `HashMap<Character, Integer>`. You can process each new character something like this:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (each character c in the file) {
    Integer code = map.get(c);
    if (code == null) {
        // new character
        code = map.size();
        map.put(c, code); // assign next number
    }
    // use code as the encoding for c
}
```